# What did you name her?

Tags: passive-voice

what did you name her? how to form its passive
I am confused here.
One of my friends asked me about this question. 
His sudden question bewildered me.
Kindly help me. 
Thanks .

Comment: What is so confusing here? How about "What was she named?" or "What name was she given?"?

Comment: Sir , what about this? By what name was she called or addressed?

Comment: Are you asking how to properly respond to that kind of question or what? The typical response in the passive voice would be, if somebody asked you that, "She was named Sylvia."

Comment: Okay, thanks to you. Sir. God bless you . Sir , how to ask someone a question personally in this platform?

Comment: You can ask right here in the comments section if you'd like or create a separate post.

Comment: @user124234: I'm sure you mean to be "polite", but you should note that Anglophones don't normally address each other as **Sir**, no matter how respectful they are.

Comment: Sorry, sir. I am from Pakistan.  We adress the respectable teachers as Sir. That's why if the teachers are teaching us here. They are our teachers, so I like to respect the teachers here.  They are Sir. Thanks.  Never mind, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody asked you that, the typical response in the passive voice would be:

> She was named Sylvia.

Comment: Sir,  I need your help.  I am interested in English.  I don't have any good teacher to guide me.  How can I improve my mistakes? How to improve my Grammar? I am totally upset about it.  Please you are our senior teachers.  You know better than me .

Comment: Go online and look for tutoring services or buy a grammar book. But nowadays almost all the information on English grammar and usage you would possibly ever need is available online completely for free. I would personally recommend this guy: http://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Your%20Teacher.html

Comment: Okay, sir thanks to you.  But sir , I like all the teachers who are working and teaching here. I want to be with them always.  I love this site so much.

Comment: Then keep your questions coming. They all will be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Sir , I just want a good teacher from this site who can help me in my Grammar.  Sir,  can you ?

Comment: I and other users are already doing exactly that by answering your questions.

Comment: @user124234 - You might also try frequenting the [ELL chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin). Be patient, though. No one will be able to teach you English in a matter of a few weeks.